# How to add a slice to a Torch7 Tensor?

Tags: lua, torch

I am using Lua and Torch 7.

How do I efficiently (without for loops) add Tensors A and B of size (1, 2048, 1024) together to produce a Tensor C of size (2, 2048, 1024)?

I am using the package and documentation at https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md but I don't see a function that can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some function are in the `torch` library instead of `tensor` 
https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md#res-torchcat-res-x_1-x_2-dimension- . 
Maybe this function will be needed to add third dimension before concatenating : 
https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#result-expandresult-sizes